# UIWebview and UIView with autolayout in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiwebview, autolayout, height

I have a custom uitableviewcell with uiwebview at the top of the cell. Below that a uiview for another custom view part. The UIView is to have width and height fixed for a screen size, but can vary based on aspect ratio of screen size. But UIWebview needs to be having synamic height adjustment based on HTML text content.

I have tried a lot. But nothing is going right. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
class EventInfoViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet var lblDescription : UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var webDescView : UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.webDescView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
            self.webDescView.scrollView.bounces = false

          //Load Description in webview
            self.lblDescription.text = Your_description as String
            self.webDescView.loadHTMLString(NSString(format: "<html> <body style='color:#AAAAAA'> %@ </body></html>", description.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "<br/>")) as String, baseURL: nil)
            self.lblDescription.sizeToFit()

    }

    //webView delegate method
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
    {
         self.webDescView.frame.size.height = self.webDescView.scrollView.contentSize.height
         // This descView is my view having frame size based on webView
         //self.descView.frame.size.height = self.webDescView.frame.size.height + 40
    }

}
```

Its working my side, hope this will also work for you. :)